# mvn release:perform tries to clone the wrong repo

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have an `mvn release:perform`, tryong to clone `git@github.com:dblock/waffle.git/waffle-pom`, which is incorrect. Where is the `waffle-pom` part coming from?

Source code in https://github.com/dblock/waffle/tree/master/Source/JNA.

`[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git clone git@github.com:dblock/waffle.git/waffle-pom C:\Users\dblock\source\waffle\dblock\Source\JNA\target\checkout"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\dblock\source\waffle\dblock\Source\JNA\target
[ERROR] The git-clone command failed.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------`

Comment: which version of the maven-release-plugin are you using? I can't find a locked version, so it could very well pick up 2.0, which is rather old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the [SCM](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#SCM) section in the `pom.xml` from which you are releasing. Default behavior is to use the SCM from the parent and extend it with the artifactId. This mechanism is based on SVN and is the default behavior of the plugin.
It would be better if there's a strategy per SCM type, because for GIT this doesn't make sense. This is something which might be fixed in the 3.x version of the plugin.
Anyhow, it is best practice to always specify SCM in the release root pom.

Comment: Thank you! That helped, I had an entry in the common pom.xml and thought that was enough. Fixed in https://github.com/dblock/waffle/commit/287a6d1ed118c8a0235cdddd8706e462dbd7e6a3, please feel free to make other suggestions on the improvements to the pom(s) - I have no idea what I am doing :)

Comment: There's too much to tell about poms and Maven, so you should be more specific. Or start reading some free books (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/maven/info), it's really worth it.